# How do I make Home Builders more fun?

Tags: house-rules

*Home Builders* is a cooperative game, published by Family Pastimes and Zonnespel/Sunny Games.

My youngest son likes it, mainly because of the theme. My eldest thinks it's boring, and I have to agree with him.

[Its rules are pretty simple](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/7911/home-builders).

First off, while it's a cooperative game, there's actually very little cooperation needed or even possible. Most of it is pure luck.

But the main objection I have is that at a certain point, which can be quite early in the game, depending on what you draw, you already know if you're going to win or lose, even though you still have to finish the game.

Ideally, I'd like to delay the moment when you know you've won, or you've lost.
There are four disasters, two repair options and two disaster prevention options. If you have at least as much prevention cards left as there are disasters left, you know you're going to win. If there are more parts of buildings destroyed than there are repair cards left, you know you can't win anymore. As I said, this can occur early in the game, depending on the luck of the draw.

How can we change this?

Comment: Sounds like you've figured out what's wrong: cooperation isn't needed/possible, winning based on luck, outcome known long before the endgame.  Fixing all those would require changing most of the game.